# Django object manager 'lower' parameter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to filter out a queryset based on if one of its field names is in a list of lower case values. The trouble is that some of these field values have capital letters, so I can't do

```
all_listings = all_listings.objects.filter(make__name__in=makes)
```

Is there a possible way to say something along the lines of

```
all_listings = all_listings.objects.filter(make__name__lower__in=makes)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [Lower func](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#lower)

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

all_listings = all_listings.objects.annotate(name_lower=Lower('make__name')).filter(name_lower__in=makes)
```

Comment: Hey Dima, I was hoping that would be it, but when I tried the query with iexact, I get the error "django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'exact' for CharField or join on the field not permitted."

Comment: Sorry, I incorrectly read your query. I changed my answer. Try it now

Comment: Very nice query Dima, thank you. Both this annotate way, and itzmeontv's regular expression filter both work. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
all_listings = all_listings.objects.filter(make__name__iregex=r'(' + '|'.join(makes) + ')')
```

Comment: Thanks itzmeontv, this query, and Dima's annotate both worked for me. If I could mark both answers correct, I would.